# Haskell binary tree fast implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, haskell, benchmarking

I implemented binary tree data structure in Haskell.

My code:

```
module Data.BTree where

data Tree a = EmptyTree 
                | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
                deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

emptyTree :: a -> Tree a  
emptyTree a = Node a EmptyTree EmptyTree

treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeInsert x EmptyTree = emptyTree x
treeInsert x  (Node a left right) 
        | x == a = (Node x left right)
        | x < a =  (Node a (treeInsert x left) right)   
        | x > a =  (Node a left (treeInsert x right))


fillTree :: Int -> Tree Int -> Tree Int
fillTree  10000 tree = tree 
fillTree  x tree = let a = treeInsert x tree
                   in fillTree (x + 1) a
```

This code very slow. I run:

```
fillTree 1 EmptyTree
```

I get : 50.24 secs

I try to implement this code in C language and my result of this test: 0m0.438s

Why so big difference? Is Haskell code rely so slow or my binary tree in haskell bad? I want to ask haskell guru maybe i can make my binary tree implementation more effective?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, how you are measuring the time, but on my computer your function takes only 3.3 secs. Did you possibly forgot to compile with `-O2`? On my machine, this halves the time taken, although most of the time is spend on rendering the tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt you implemented the same code in C.  You probably used a non-persistent tree structure instead.  <strike>That means you're comparing an O(n^2) algorithm in Haskell to an O(n) algorithm in C.</strike>  Nevermind, the specific case you're using would be O(n^2) with a persistent structure or not.  There's just a lot more allocation with the persistent structure, so it's not a fundamental algorithmic difference.

Additionally, it looks like you ran this from ghci.  That 'i' in "ghci" means "interpreter".  And yes, the interpreter can be tens or hundreds of times slower than compiled code.  Try compiling it with optimizations and running it.  <strike>I suspect it'll still be slower due to fundamental algorithmic differences, but it won't be near 50 seconds.</strike>

Answer (score 14):

First, another data point: The `Set` data structure in the `Data.Set` module happens to be a binary tree. I've translated your `fillTree` function to use it, instead:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Set (Set)

fillSet :: Int -> Set Int -> Set Int
fillSet 10000 set = set
fillSet x set = let a = Set.insert x set
                in fillSet (x + 1) a
```

Running `fillSet 1 Set.empty` in GHCi, including a bit of extra computation to be sure that the entire result is evaluated, runs with no perceptible delay. So, this seems to indicate that the problem lies in your implementation.

To start with, I suspect the biggest difference between using `Data.Set.Set` vs. your implementation is that if I'm reading your code correctly, you're not actually testing a binary tree. You're testing an over-complicated linked list--i.e., a maximally unbalanced tree--as a result of inserting elements in increasing order. `Data.Set.Set` uses a *balanced* binary tree, which handles the pathological input better in this case.

We can also look at the definition of `Set`:

```
data Set a = Tip 
           | Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size a !(Set a) !(Set a)
```

Without going into too much detail, what this says is that tracks the size of the tree, and avoids a few less-than-useful layers of indirection that would otherwise exist in the data type.

The full source of the `Data.Set` module can be found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-Set.html); you may find it enlightening to study.

---

A few more observations, to demonstrate the difference between different ways of running it. I added the following to your code:

```
toList EmptyTree = []
toList (Node x l r) = toList l ++ [x] ++ toList r

main = print . sum . toList $ fillTree 1 EmptyTree
```

This traverses the tree, sums the elements, and prints the total, which should ensure that everything is forced. My system is probably somewhat unusual so you may get rather different results trying this yourself, but relative differences should be accurate enough. Some results:

- Using `runhaskell`, which should be roughly equivalent to running it in GHCi:

  ```
  real    1m36.055s
  user    0m0.093s
  sys     0m0.062s
  ```
- Building with `ghc --make -O0`:

  ```
  real    0m3.904s
  user    0m0.030s
  sys     0m0.031s
  ```
- Building with `ghc --make -O2`:

  ```
  real    0m1.765s
  user    0m0.015s
  sys     0m0.030s
  ```

Using my equivalent function based on `Data.Set` instead:

- Using `runhaskell`:

  ```
  real    0m0.521s
  user    0m0.031s
  sys     0m0.015s
  ```
- Using `ghc --make -O2`:

  ```
  real    0m0.183s
  user    0m0.015s
  sys     0m0.031s
  ```

And the moral of today's story is: **Evaluating expressions in GHCi and timing them with a stopwatch is a very, very bad way to test the performance of your code.**

Comment: Yeah, this is why it's an O(n^2) algorithm, rather than O(n log n).  I should have made a note about it being a degenerate case in my answer.  Of course, I also should have done the complexity analysis correctly the first time.